# Transposing tables

Tags: python, transpose

I'm a beginner to python and are trying to transpose the following table:

```
Column1 Column2
x        3
y        4
```

I'm expecting the following output:

```
x
x
x
y
y
y
y
```

What is the best way to get this output?

Comment: How are you reading the table? Is it a csv file or something else? Also make sure to include your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = [3, 4]
b = ['cheese', 'corn']

c = [(b + ' ')*a for a, b in zip(a,b)]
d = [element.split() for element in c]

array = np.array([item for sublist in c for item in sublist])
```

Now you will have an array with copies of your strings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what data structure you are using for your table, but if you have a pandas DataFrame you could create a flattened list as follows.

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['x', 3], ['y', 4]], columns=['col1', 'col2'])
df
```

Output:

```
col1    col2
x       3
y       4
```

Input:

```
flattened_table = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    flattened_table += (row.values[0] * row.values[1])
flattened_table
```

Output:

```
['x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y']
```